# Detecting UTF8 name

Tags: c#, websocket, buffer

I am streaming data to my buffer and one of the possible packets I may receive starts with the byte 5 and is UTF-8 encoded (no fixed size in bytes) is there any way I may detect this? Currently if I do

```
    do
    {
        WebSocketReceiveResult result = await Conn.ReceiveAsync(readBuffer, token);
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(readBuffer.Array, 0, result.Count));
    }
```

I can see it appear.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's a BOM marker at the beginning of the stream there is no way you can know for sure - you usually know in advance from the context (documentation or convention) whether the data you receive is in UTF-8 or some other format.

I good primer on Unicode can be found here:

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/printerFriendly/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: I already know it is in UTF-8 and I know that the packet starts with 5, I just don't know the length